# Java Native Interface (JNI)

Tags: java, selenium, java-native-interface

I'm using Java and Selenium on a VPS. I need to execute a specific set of Selenium code under a different windows user account. I know Java does not support this functionality. I came across Java Native Interface which supposedly supports this functionality - can anyone show me how I'd use this to run code under another user account?

Note: I'm aware of Selenium Grid however there's certain functionality Selenium Grid does not support therefore I want to execute standard Selenium code under a different windows user account (locally).

Thanks

Comment: `I know Java does not support this functionality` - That's not entirely true. Java can tell you the actual username of the logged user. You could use it to choose what to execute, if I'm understanding the requirement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood requirement.. I do not want to find the username of logged in user.. I need to execute a specific set of code under another user account. Like if I'm logged into user Y I want to execute code under user X.. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. Then I'd use JNA rather than JNI. A little tutorial for your requirement can be found here: [Start a process as an another user using JNA (Windows)](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-start-process-as-another-user-using-jna.html) - In case you find the solution for your requirement, I'd suggest to post it as answer, to help other users that might have the same requirement in the future

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for but I still need to wrap by head around it.. Apparently, I could access a remote server too not just local server with this code, is this correct? Also if I login to the seconds user account via RDP while executing selenium code, presumably I should be able to see the code running correct (using this framework), correct?

Comment: I don't know, I would say yes, JNA lets you use windows libraries in your Java application, so ideally you can do everything you can do in windows (such as RDP login, etc). But you'll need to investigate, I'm not sure, I don't know JNA *that* good